# Download Email Attachment with Python from Gmail

Tags: python, email, gmail, attachment, okta

I try to fedge attachments from my company GMail Account.
When trying to run the following script it won't stop loading even after 3 Minutes.

Only explanation could be that my company uses "Okta" to authorize.

```
import imaplib
import base64
import os
import email


mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com',993)
mail.login('something@gmail.com', 'xxxxxx')

mail.select('Inbox')
```

Any idea on why code wont run?

Comment: atleast for me it does not keep trying or wait it says invalid credentails even if i provide the right ones

Comment: You used your own credentials and it didn't work?

Comment: Yes i used my own credentials and it did not worked i doublt google has terminated the less secure applications support may be it has some thing to do with that feature

Comment: standard login and password may work when you run GMail in web browser - but for other programs it may need to generate separated login and password. Eventually you may try to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser and use standard login and password in web browser. I'm not sure how it works when you use [GMail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api) - it may also need to generate `Secret KEY` to access data (and it may need to accept access to data from own application)